# ListView Line Up Text and Images center to each other

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am using ListView and trying to align the 2nd line of text and images perfectly next to each other but can't get it right

Must I rather use LinearLayout or is the Relative Layout fine and I am just missing something

[image]

Must look like this

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button_a"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button_a"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/title_textview"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

you might want to control the layout more by defining the width and height of the ImageViews and use specific sized resources to make sure the layout looks good on any device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:text="text"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button_a"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/image_button_a"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```